# making a class "thread safe" in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, thread-safety

I'm reading the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html) around Thread Safety, and it's not completely clear to me what (in practice) really constitutes a class being thread safe.  To help understand this better, what would would all need to be done to the following class to make it thread safe (and why)?

```
#import "UnsafeQueue.h"

@interface UnsafeQueue()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *data;

@end

@implementation UnsafeQueue

- (id)peek {
    return [self.data firstObject];
}

- (NSUInteger)length {
    return [self.data count];
}

- (void)enqueue:(id)datum {
    [self.data addObject:datum];
}

// other methods omitted...

@end
```

Would simply creating an ivar NSLock and then lock/unlock surrounding *all* interactions with the underlying NSMutableArray?

Does the length method, which is just asking for the array's count, need to do this as well?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The easiest and best way to make a class thread safe is to make it immutable. Then you don't have to deal with any of this. It just works. It really is worth your time to think about whether you need mutability on multiple threads.

But if an immutable class creates significant problems for your design, then generally the best way to implement it is with GCD rather than locks. GCD has much lower overhead and is generally speaking easier to get right.

In this particular case, I'd implement it along these lines (untested, and I've been working in Swift for a while now, so forgive me if I drop a semicolon):

```
#import "SafeQueue.h"

@interface SafeQueue()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *data;
@property (strong, nonatomic) dispatch_queue_t dataQueue;

@end

@implementation SafeQueue

- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _dataQueue = dispatch_queue_create("SafeQueue.data", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)peek {
    __block id result = nil;
    dispatch_sync(self.dataQueue, ^{ result = [self.data firstObject] });
    return result;
}

- (NSUInteger)length {
    __block NSUInteger result = 0;
    dispatch_sync(self.dataQueue, ^{ result = [self.data count] });
    return result;
}

- (void)enqueue:(id)datum {
    dispatch_barrier_async(self.dataQueue, ^{ [self.data addObject:datum] });
}

// other methods omitted...

@end
```

Note the use of `dispatch_sync` for all readers and `dispatch_barrier_async` for all writers. This is how you keep your overhead to a minimum by allowing parallel readers and exclusive writers. And if there is no contention (which is the normal case), `dispatch_sync` has much lower overhead than a lock (`NSLock` or `@synchronized` or even a pthreads lock).

See [Migrating Away from Threads](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html) for more advice from Apple on how to better deal with concurrency in Cocoa.

Comment: I definitely understand the benefits of immutability (and probably should've prefaced this question with that).  I've stumbled across the dispatch_* functions, but will definitely have to look into them more, thanks.

Could you explain at a lower, fundamental level, why the readers need to be synchronized?

Comment: @chinabuffet What if another thread `enqueued`, but neglected to update its `length` property yet? What if that other thread was in the process updating the `length` property, had updated the first byte of the `length`'s internal representation, but hadn't gotten around to updating the second byte? By synchronizing readers with writers, you're protecting yourself against this. The beauty of reader-writer pattern is that with a concurrent queue, writes are synchronized with barrier, but reads are allowed to take place concurrently with other reads: Synchronized where needed, but not otherwise.

Comment: Expanding on what @Rob said here, another beauty of this pattern is that writers don't actually block against each other. They're serial, but not blocking. So having lots of simultaneous reads is highly efficient. Having lots of simultaneous writes is *also* efficient. The only thing that creates contention is when you have many reads and writes going on at the same time (but that's expensive in all schemes).

Comment: In a simple iOS app, say something like instagram/Gmail, where would I possibly need to be doing something thread safe? I mean, isn't it always one user, one device, one mainthread, and some background thread doing database kind of stuff?  i.e. there is no thread that would be messing with any other thread unless I applying some sort of a bad coding approach?

Comment: @asma22 thread safe data structures are one solution to thread interaction. The scale doesn't matter. The moment you have "some background thread" you have to worry about all the issues. You have race conditions or you don't. Background threads often have to interact with data the UI will deal with. One solution is to pass data between threads and never allow two threads to see the same data at the same time. That often works in Cocoa. But often it doesn't well and a shared data structure is better. Logging is a common example. Producer/consumer queues are as well.

Comment: Thread safe data structures also hide the threading details from the caller. Unsafe data structures require the caller to know more about the implementation details to use the structure correctly. Thread safe implementations hide more of that detail. "You must always call me on X queue" (especially when X is not main) is very fragile. Thread safe data structures allow changing implementation details without impacting callers. So it can be very useful. But it's just a tool.

Comment: I think I understand the concept. But I don't understand a general use case for it. I may understand better with an example. Where could we possibly have multiple threads accessing the data structure. Can you please give me an example for **the exact moment that its needed in** app like Instagram or Gmail? I mean their is one entity which is the mainThread--UI thread asking something to be done in the background. It's not like I have multiple screens at the same time, working on the same data.

Comment: Consider the case that your UI is logging (and therefore putting something on an array of things to be logged a synchronously) and your database processing thread is also logging. You can use dispatch_async directly, or you can wrap it in a function that calls dispatch_async, or can have an array that is thread safe (which means it internally uses a dispatch_async; it winds up somewhere).  Consider a parallel processing algorithm that is sharing shared results (such as many images that are being processed in parallel). Again, having a thread safe array can be a very convenient way to manage it

Comment: Using Gmail as an example of a "simple application" is not a good example btw. Gmail as I remember is a web app in a native wrapper. I've never used Instagram, but I suspect it is quite complex under the covers. One of the most complex apps I've worked on was a "simple" chat application.

Comment: As an example: we are downloading images and want to put them in your `arrayOfImages`. *each* `imageData` is setting a *single* element in an `arrayOfImages`. I mean its not that they are working on the same index of the Array? Or is that you are saying that maybe the download of images is done asynchronously and it could be that the same exact moment 2 of the `imageData`s may be attempting to `addObject` into an 'identical index of array'--and that could be problematic?

Comment: I fear you misunderstand how arrays multi-threading works. It is unsafe for one thread to be reading an array while another thread appends to it. It has nothing to do with accessing the same element. Reading and writing simultaneously to any part of an array is undefined behavior. Appending to an array may cause the entire array to reallocate and be moved to another part of memory. If you're trying to read from it at the same time, you can wind up looking at invalid memory. This isn't an weird edge case; it happens all the time.

Comment: With Swift.Array, modifying any element of the array may cause the entire thing to be relocated, causing the same problem. It is not safe to modify NSArray or Swift.Array on multiple threads simultaneously. (Even C arrays can have significant problems depending on your processor and data types. It's definitely not well-defined behavior.)

Comment: Iknow its undefined and shouldn't be done but it can be done and create crashes ie before setting a value you `dealloc` it and then maybe right then from another thread you try to read, which will create a problem, a race-condition and thread safety is about handling race-conditions. I feel like I *can't* convey my question-- **which is at what moment of a *single user* App your Thread-safety may get challenged?** You said you worked for a chat app; Can you *please* give an example of at what moment in WhatsApp thread safety may get challenged? Which property may be simultaneously set/get?

Comment: I had a buddy list that is fetched from the server; that's done in the background and the buddy list is updated asynchronously. The UI reads the buddy list to display it on the main thread. It is possible (and even reasonably likely) for the buddy list to change while the UI is reading it. You have to prevent that from happening or crashing was likely. Buddies had availability and avatars. Those changed all the time in the background. Threading was a continual concern.

Comment: `dealloc` isn't the issue here (it can be, but often isn't). It's not safe to read from an array *at all* while that array is being modified on another thread. It is not safe to read any property while that property is being modified elsewhere (property updates are not promised to be atomic; you can get half of the old address and half of the new address, pointing to garbage memory and crash).

Comment: @Honey  instagram is not a good example here, they use an asynchron UI framework.

Answer (score 6):

Bottom line, the first step to thread-safety is to ensure that you don't have one thread mutating the object (with it in a possibly inconsistent state) while you're trying to access it from another. So any of a variety of synchronization techniques can be useful. See [Synchronization](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1) section of the *Threading Programming Guide* for more information on a variety of types of mechanisms. The reader-writer pattern illustrated by Rob Napier is far more efficient than the `@synchronized` directive or `NSLock` and is discussed in WWDC 2012 video [Asynchronous Design Patterns with Blocks, GCD, and XPC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=712).

By the way, the `peek` and `length` methods have diminished utility in multi-threaded environment. These suggest a dependency that the naive developer might incorrectly infer between these methods and other methods. For example, just because `length` is greater than zero doesn't mean that when you subsequently go to retrieve it, that anything will be there.

I would take a hard look at those methods and ask yourself whether they make sense in the multithreaded environment. I know you probably just meant these are arbitrary examples of thread-safety in mutable arrays, but it's indicative of a broader problem I see frequently in "thread-safe" examples I've seen elsewhere on Stack Overflow, where the synchronization mechanism is often at the wrong level to bear any utility.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yeah this isn't something I'm actually building, its just a contrived example I came up with to have as a talking point in my original question.

In your second paragraph about why those methods have diminished utility -- could you expand on that a bit more?  Are you saying that because they'd ultimately end up being compound actions, the only way to use those safely in a multithreaded environment to do something like `@synchronized(queue)` around the length, and then do a peek?

Comment: My point is that if you synchronize `length` as contemplated in Napier's or paul's answers, all you're guaranteeing is that the number returned is valid and internally consistent with the state of the queue object _at the moment `length` was called._ But the value returned is also immediately obsolete because by the time the calling thread uses the returned value, another thread might have mutated the queue object. In this case, the solution is probably to deprecate `length` and `peek`, and only have `enqueue` and `dequeue` methods.

Comment: The analogy is the `viewWillAppear` method: With the introduction of cancelable, interactive animated transitions, you're no longer guaranteed that `viewDidAppear` will follow `viewWillAppear`. At WWDC, they joked that `viewWillAppear` could be renamed to called `viewMightAppear` or `viewWillProbablyAppear` or `iReallyWishThisViewWouldAppear`. So, following that analogy, the `length` method might be called `lengthUsedToBeButCouldBeDifferentNow`. lol.

Answer (score 5):

Thread safety means that the data structure can be accessed and/or modified by multiple threads without becoming corrupt.

One simple approach is to use Objective-C's `@synchronized` capability.

In this case, `@synchronized(self.data)` around all of your accesses to the array will ensure that only a single thread can access the array at a time.

Even though `length` doesn't modify the array, you still need to protect its access because another thread could potentially modify the array -

```
#import "SafeQueue.h"

@interface SafeQueue()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *data;

@end

@implementation SafeQueue

- (id)peek {
    @synchronized (self.data) {
        return [self.data firstObject];
    }
}

- (NSUInteger)length {
    @synchronized(self.data) {
        return [self.data count];
    }
}

- (void)enqueue:(id)datum {
    @synchronized(self.data) {
        [self.data addObject:datum];
    }
}

// other methods omitted...

@end
```

Comment: Upvoted since I can only accept 1 answer :(  Could you give an example (like the sequence of events) where not synchronizing a read could lead to problems?